# Which techniques are used by Java DI frameworks for dependency injection?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I recently learned from http://dig.floatingsun.net/dagger-vs-guice/ that Google Guice surprisingly is using Reflection to inject dependencies. Up to now I was under the impression that most Java dependency injection frameworks use more sophisticated and more performant techniques for that. But maybe this is not true. What kind of techniques do the different frameworks use for dependency injection?